# Change row knockout template every 8th row

Tags: jquery, knockout-mapping-plugin

Using knockout template binding I am binding a table like below:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="PrintLabelsTemplate">
    <TR> 
        <TD data-bind="text: CustomerFirstName"></TD>
        <TD data-bind="text: ModelDescription"></TD> 
    </TR>
</script>

<div>
    <table style="border-collapse: collapse;"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%" id="tblPrintLabels" class="pme-main" data-bind="template: {name:'PrintLabelsTemplate', foreach: ViewModel}">
    </table>
</div>
```

All working fine for me, but my issue is after every 8 rows repeated I want to insert different row with one image background like

```
<tr>
    <td>Breaking Row</td>
</tr>
```

So how can I write this logic in template binding?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use CSS for this. You could use the CSS property `:nth-child(7)` to specify different CSS properties for the seventh item. Then I would use the `:after` selector with the `content` CSS property to insert an additional row with whatever you want the background to be.

This has some advantages of not forcing your Knockout code to do anything out of the ordinary and if it is just a visual separator that repeats every 8th row it separates your presentation from your code.

Here is an explination for the [nth-child](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) and [css content](http://css-tricks.com/css-content/)

Comment: but i need to find after every 8 rows

Comment: Do you need to find it, or insert a custom one every 8th row?